# Determining CUDA compute capability as constexpr for __launch_bounds__

Tags: c++, cuda

In order to launch a CUDA kernel efficiently I'd like to use `__launch_bounds__` with arguments that depend on the maximal threads per SM allowed in the current GPU, which in turn depends on that GPU's compute capability.

One way to do that is via `cudaDeviceProp` structure returned from `cudaGetDeviceProperties`. Unfortunately, that wouldn't do: `__launch_bounds__` requires its arguments to be `constexpr`. Therefore I cannot call `cudaGetDeviceProperties` for the purpose of specifying `__launch_bounds__`.

Thus the question: how do I determine either the maximal threads per SM (preferred) or the CUDA capabilities number **at compile time** so that I could pass that into `__launch_bounds__`?

Comment: The official docs on `__launch_bounds__` says _"Optimal launch bounds for a given kernel will usually differ across major architecture revisions"_. There's ~10 of them, I'd say just hardcode it like the example they gave.

Comment: @PasserBy, hardcoding is not safe against future changes. We had a hardcoded assumption that starting with 3.5 max threads per SM is at least 2048, because this is what nVidia did from 3.5 until 7.0. And with 7.5, lo and behold, they **decreased** it to 1024. Which, incidentally, prompted this question. How can you hardcode the future hardware changes that may include both increased and decreased capabilities?

Comment: You can't. Low level optimizations tend to be hairy. You can emit warnings when you detect unknown architectures.

Comment: Perhaps have not so performant fallback profiles? The Cuda device parameters at least stay in a certain range (hopefully). But sometimes your algorithms really need a certain amount of shared memory or threads or registers available.

Comment: You can template the parameters to `__launch_bounds__`  and statically generate as many kernels necessary to cover the  hardware profiles you need. Because the parameters are templated, you will get a unique symbol for each that can be selected at runtime